# I want to use a silverlight TabItem as a button container

Tags: silverlight, tabcontrol, tabitem

I want zero functionality and appearance.  I also want it to be all the way to the right of the tab strip.  does anyone have any pointers as to how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Can you be a little more specific? What does zero functionality and appearance mean in the context of your question?

Comment: Sure.  I want the tab itself to be invisible.  I removed the border and the background but the mouseover fade effect still appears.  I also want the click event to do nothing, meaning the TabControl still displayswhatever tab was already displayed.  I think I can do this my cancelling the event but I'm not sure how to do that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not all visual features of a Control can be customized by the standard properties (BorderBrush, Background, etc.)  You need to edit the ControlTemplate of the TabItem to hide the mouse over effect.

You will also need to edit the ControlTemplate of the parent TabControl.  Put a transparent Rectangle over the strip that hosts the TabItems to capture mouse events.  You will also need to set IsTabStop = false for al your TabItems to disable keyboard interaction.